# Why setDeleteAction and setUpdateAction only?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to create two buttons, one for activating a checked system user and the other to deactivate a checked system user, but if I use a different function name it doesnt work if I use these two functions it works. Why? is it a must to use them?

```js
function setUpdateAction() {
  document.activate.action = "includes/vendors/activate.php";
  document.activate.submit();
}


function setDeleteAction() {
  document.activate.action = "includes/vendors/deactivate.php";
  document.activate.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="activate" method="post" action="">
  <td><input type="button" name="update" value="Activate" onClick="setUpdateAction();"></td> 
  <td><input type="button" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"  onClick="setDeleteAction();" />
</form>
```

Comment: there is nothing like that you must be missing somewhere. Provide/ fiddle the code that doesn't work

Comment: Ok let me check and see if I missed something. Thanks Kishore

Answer (score 1):

No, function names in JavaScript are arbitrary.

You must, however, make the function names agree in the `onClick` attribute and the function declaration in your JavaScript. As long as the identifier names are spelled the same, you should be able to name the functions whatever you like [within reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names).

Comment: Thanks amphetamachine, I will try to check on it again.